# Auto screen lock pattern / password enable or not?

Tags: android

i am developing app which check whether user has selected any screen lock pattern or not .

if not i will call the intent to start activity to set the password then continue the app

so that i ask user to set the screen lock first by calling the

```
    Intent intent =
new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
```

startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DevicePolicyManager.isActivePasswordSufficient` to check whether password is set or not.

You need to call `DevicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality` and

```
DevicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength
```

before calling this function

**Edit**: Here's the code.

Suppose you want the user to have any password to be set then use below code.

```
DevicePolicyManager  mDPM = DevicePolicyManager.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE); mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(ControllerActivity.this, DeviceAdminSample.class);

mDPM.setPasswordQuality(mDeviceAdminSample, DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING );
if(!mDPM.isActivePasswordSufficient()){
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Ofcourse you will have to have all the permissions related to device policy manager

Comment: can u explain in word what these three functions do , thanx for help

Comment: Developer.android.com can: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

Comment: i have read but don't understanding can u please explain with example thanx

Comment: i have updated the answer, but you really should check the deviceadmin sample code in api demos for a better understanding

Comment: can u please tell can i add text when asking for password set

Answer (score 0):

Replace

if(DevicePolicyManager.isActivePasswordSufficient()){

With

if(!mDPM.isActivePasswordSufficient()){